# Easing entry of sudo password for remote hosts?

Tags: ssh, password, sudo

I'm logging on to remote hosts via SSH to do server admin. The login uses a cert but I login as a normal user (`ssh -p $PORT $USER@$HOST`) and use `sudo` to run commands. It's a pain to have to enter the `sudo` password all the time - which I do by finding it from a flat text file and cut-pasting in - but using `sudo -i` seems inadvisable.

Is there a way to make this easier, like keeping my password on a hotkey. Just seems clunky - it would be good to have a password manager that handles this.

I use Kubuntu 14.04 and use `kdewallet` for local password management. Thanks for any suggestions to ease this.

Answer (score 0):

It's in the nature of `sudo` to require typing in the password at login and after the password cache expired. If you keep your `sudo` password in an unencrypted text file (and even in an encrypted it's a bad idea) and want to manage it with `kdewallet` you don't have to worry about `sudo -i` because it's a much more secure alternative for your use case.

Ah, and learn your sudo password by hard and delete the text file (consider using `shred` for the file) :) It's an immense security risk!

Comment: I need to know approximately 100 passwords for various systems including sometimes just having short term passwords. Yes having a plaintext file is a security risk if my main system is compromised - but if it's compromised then access to my email means all those passwords can be reset barring a very few that use 2FA.

Any way - I don't consider "just commit it to memory" to be a valid solution to remembering say 20 x 24 character strings for use in sudo prompts.

Comment: The problem with "sudo -i" is that it doesn't involve the mental check on each command that ask for the sudo password - I want to retain that.